# How to wrap `new` without losing the generic parameters for the constructed type

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I want to pass a constructor and its parameters to a function and have the result not lose type information:

```
const _new = <A, B>(a: A[], b: new (a: A[]) => B) => new b(a)
const set = _new([1, 2], Set) // -> Set<unknown>
```

In this example the result is `Set<unknown>`, but I'd like it to be `Set<number>` the same as if it would be when constructed directly:

```
const set = new Set([1, 2]) // -> Set<number>
```

Specifying the generic type like this works but I want it to be automatic:

```
const set = _new([1, 2], Set<number>) // -> Set<number>
```

Is there a way to achieve this in TS?

**Edit**:

Apparently the issue is the constructor method overloading in `lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts`, because alone both of these interfaces produce the correct type (`Set<number>`), but not when merged.

```
interface SetConstructor {
  new <T>(iterable?: Iterable<T> | null): Set<T>
}
interface SetConstructor {
  new <T = any>(values?: readonly T[] | null): Set<T>
  readonly prototype: Set<any>
}
```

**Edit 2**: [Simplified example of the error in TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE5QLxQN4CgpQD0hscAtmRAsAJYIDmUcArsEwtHAGZTAAW0GgBMqtAMYBDADZMAbhFRS4EoUihcaADwhr+0Bajip8UDgHcoAHgCCAPgAUEgFxRrAbQC6AShcBlCMA2tibmVnaOLu7efgFBuAC+uCJiUhKo0GKIKKTIaC7wucaZuVDFKKjMYmxYNgA0UABCDs6unvUARi6hEa3emLaNXv2mEBbtjl64xFAAoqiGqC7MCADWCHBmCFA0autsEkhINPQIEu1S0MBwpsxk7Qq4ZWxIATGBCLf3qANYTxVV9jcAEZ6gAmeoAZg89QK5UmQA)